# Vue component does not show

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am a beginner in Vue.js and in web development in general.
I was following the vuejs guide here.

I was wondering when I was creating a vue component by `Vue.component(NameOfComponent, {...})` and adding it to my HTML like this  `<NameOfComponent></NameofComponent>`, the component did not show.

Like in the example below. The first argument of `Vue.component` is **TodoItem** which is the name of the component. When I added it as `<TodoItem></TodoItem>`, it did not show and there is an error: **[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: `<todoitem>` - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.** But `<todo-item></todo-item>` or even `<todo-Item></todo-Item>` showed.

Why? What name/naming convention should I use? Thank you!

```js
Vue.component('TodoItem', {
  template: '<li>This is a todo</li>'
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <title>Vue docs</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='app'>
    <ol>
      <TodoItem></TodoItem>
    </ol>
  </div>

  <script src='main.js'></script>
</body>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the default (kebab-case) to view the component

```js
Vue.component('TodoItem', {
  template: '<li>This is a todo</li>'
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <title>Vue docs</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='app'>
    <ol>
      <todo-item></todo-item>         // comment - Line changed
    </ol>
  </div>

  <script src='main.js'></script>
</body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way I could use `<TodoItem></TodoItem>`? How would I know the correct name to use when adding the component to HTML? For example my component name is **TodoItemList**, what is the correct name to use in HTML? `<todo-item-list></todo-item-list>`?

Comment: '-' will be placed before every Caps letter

Comment: Vue automatically by default maps CamelCase components with kebab-case names. So your component name SideBar which is in camelCase automatically gets mapped with name side-bar which is in kebab-case. In the html template it is advised to use kebab case instead of camelCase and in Javascript it is advised to use camelCase instead of kebab-case. They are just styling conventions.

Comment: so there is nothing I can't do about it. If my component name is in camel case, the only way I could use it in HTML is by its kebab-case. Thanks!